# Cannot add values to Combobox in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, combobox

I am trying to add values to Comboboxes which are created by a macro on a worksheet. The comboboxes are created but I'm unable to populate data in them.

I get

> runtime error 438: Object doesn't support this property...

I tried to declare sComboBox as Shape/Object/left it blank also but to no avail. Code errors out on `.list` property. VBA intellisense also doesn't pick up the `.list` property. I tried using OLEObjects also but I get different compiler errors.

The other question is: How do I create comboboxes in specific cells so they are not floating around or overlapping each other?

```
Dim sComboBox
If (wsTO.Cells(intLoopCounter, 5).Value <> "") Then
    cBoxName = "cBox" & wsTO.Cells(intLoopCounter, 5).Value
    Set sComboBox = wsTO.Shapes.AddFormControl(xlDropDown, Left:=Cells(intLoopCounter, 12).Left, _
        Top:=Cells(intLoopCounter + 1, 12).Top, Width:=250, Height:=25)

    With sComboBox
        .Name = cBoxName
        .List = Array("Apple", "Orange")
    End With 
End If
```

Comment: When intellisense is inexistent, hit F2 in vbe. Have you tried to compile your code with option explicit?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of :

```
With sComboBox
    .Name = cBoxName
    .List = Array("Apple", "Orange")
End With
```

Use :

```
        With sComboBox
            .Name = cBoxName
            .ControlFormat.List = Array("Apple", "Orange")
        End With
```

or :

```
        With sComboBox
            .Name = cBoxName
            .ControlFormat.AddItem "Apple"
            .ControlFormat.AddItem "Orange"
            .ControlFormat.AddItem "Peach"
        End With
```